# Angular 2 - Cannot read property '0' of undefined error

Tags: angular, angular-template

I retrieve my JSON file from this URL [http://www.bcetupes.info/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&_embed]

In my template, I have this code

```
  <p *ngFor="let news of newsObj">
      {{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]['id']}}
  </p>
```

The problem is that in my JSON file "wp:featuredmedia" can be missing. I have tried several things for example {{news._embedded.featuredmedia?[0]?.id}} but I don't know how to fix this problem in the template.

I need test if "wp:featuredmedia" exists in my object...

Comment: there is no "news_embeded"with your json

Comment: wrap it in <div *ngIf="condition"> </div>

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the object you are accessing exists before you access it or you will encounter a run time error. Here is one way to handle it using `*ngIf`:

```
<p *ngFor="let news of newsObj">
   <span *ngIf="news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"] !== undefined">
     {{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]['id']}}
   </span>
</p>
```